# Unknown Column in 'field list' but column name is matching

Tags: spring, jpa

Iam trying using spring boot jpa specification to retrive requests list:

I got this error when trying to get the list the id column exists on the database: Unknown column 'request0_4_.id' in 'field list';
///

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "request")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Request implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "identifier", nullable = false)
    private String identifier;

    @Column(name = "validation_comment")
    private String validationComment;
   @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Request request = (Request) o;
        if (request.getId() == null || getId() == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(getId(), request.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getId());
    }
}
```

// getting list

```
 Specification<Request> requestSpecification = Specification.where((root, query, cb) -> {
            query.distinct(true);
            query.orderBy(cb.desc(root.get("id")));
            return cb.and();
        });
        requestSpecification = requestSpecification.and(
                (root, query, cb) -> cb.equal(root.get("id"), 2)
        );
        List<Request> result = workflowRepository.findAll(requestSpecification);
```